# como reemplazar codigo

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente archivo s.myex:

```
func a (a):
    console.log("b")


func b (b):
    console.log("a")
```

Uso el siguiente archivo statements.json:

```
[
    {
        "mc":[["if (", "if("], "replacer", [") :", "):"], "replacer", "\n:"],
        "js":["if(", "replacer", "){", "replacer", "\n}"],
        "name":"if"
    },
    {
        "mc":["func ", "replacer", ["(", " ("], "replacer", [") :", "):"], "replacer", "\n:"],
        "js":["function ", "replacer", "(", "replacer", "){", "replacer", "\n}"],
        "name":"func"
    }
]
```

Este archivo Statement.js:

```
class Statement {
    constructor(js, myCode) {
        if (js.length === myCode.length) {
            this.js = js;
            this.myCode = myCode;
            
        } else {
            console.error('Wrong number of arguments');
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
    convertCode(str) {        
        let strFinal = String(str);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.myCode.length; i++) {
            if (typeof this.myCode[i] === "string") {
                if (this.myCode[i] != "replacer") {
                    if (strFinal.indexOf(this.myCode[i]) !== -1) {
                        console.log(this.myCode[i]);
                        strFinal = strFinal.replace(this.myCode[i], this.js[i]);
                    } else {   
                        return;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let valid = false;
                for (let j = 0; j < this.myCode[i].length; j++) {
                    
                    if (strFinal.indexOf(this.myCode[i][j]) !== -1) {
                        console.log(this.myCode[i][j]);
                        valid = true;
                        strFinal = strFinal.replace(this.myCode[i][j], this.js[i])
                    }
                    if (!valid) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return strFinal;
    }
}

module.exports.Statement = Statement;
```

Y el main.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Statements = require("./Statements/Statements.json");
var Statement = require("./Statement").Statement;

function create () {
    var statements = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < Statements.length; i++) {
        statements[Statements[i].name] = new Statement(Statements[i].js, Statements[i].mc);
    }
    return statements;
}
var file = "";
for (const key in process.argv) {
    if (process.argv.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (process.argv[key].startsWith("file=")){
            file = process.argv[key].split("=")[1]
        }
    }
}

fs.readFile(file + ".myex", function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw(err);
    var finalData = "";
    var statements = create();
    dataArray = String(data).split(";\r\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        for (const key in statements) {
            var statementJS = ""
            if (statements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                const statement = statements[key];
                statementJS = statement.convertCode(dataArray[i]);
                if (statementJS) {
                    finalData += statementJS
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
  
  fs.appendFile(file + '.js', finalData, 'utf8', () => {})
})
```

Pero, cuando ejecuto `node main.js file=s`, en la terminal el archivo `s.js` esta vacío; debería tener el código de `s.myex` compilado en código js.

Uso node.js, pero no se como convertir el código a javascript.

Comment: No entendí. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y agrega a la pregunta lo que has intentado, qué errores tienes y ejemplos de la salida que esperas obtener.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con *esa estructura*. En todo caso, muestra el código concreto con el que estás trabajando y el problema, salida y/o error que estás teniendo así como una muestra de lo que esperas obtener.